# SQL Query to check if joining record exists

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables - User table (`tblUsers`) and Logs table (`tblLogs`).

The User table contains - `UserID` and `UserName`.

The Logs table contains - `UserID`, `ApplicationID`, `ApplicationName`, `LogonDateTime`

I want to select all the Users and find if they have accessed a particular application (for example `ApplicationID = 3`)

**Output expected**

```
UserID, UserName, Status
```

Status - If he has visited the `applicationID = 3` or not.

Comment: Have you tried anything  already? What problems have you faced?

Comment: When you say "application 3", do you mean that the ApplicationID column will be _3_?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and it's expected result!

Comment: you are missing a third table which contain all the applications available ( i guess it's `tblApplications` )

Comment: why is the question related to duplicate rows?

Comment: I have written a simple left outer join and it works fine. My problem is there are users are duplicated when he has used two application. For example if userID 1 has used applicationID 2 and 3, then I get two rows. One says visited and the other not visited

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query give you the direction of thought as to what you exact requirement is:

```
SELECT u.UserID,
   u.UserName,
   (SELECT (CASE
                WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN
                 'VISITED'
                ELSE
                 NULL
              END)
         FROM tblLogs l
        WHERE u.UserId = l.UserId
          AND l.ApplicationID = '3')
        AS status
  FROM tblUsers u
```

Note that based on the DB that you use, the group by on UserName and ApplicationName might be optional.

Comment: I don't have to count anything

Answer (score 0):

Since you are missing a third table which contain all the applications available ( i guess it's `[tblApplications]` ), the sql would be:

```
SELECT
      U.UserID
    , U.UserName
    , (
        CASE WHEN L.ApplicationID IS NOT NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
        END
    ) AS Status 
FROM tblUsers AS U, tblApplications AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLogs AS L
    ON A.ID = L.ApplicationID
WHERE A.ID = '3'
```

Comment: This will not work.. Why do you need application table?

Comment: You have to join by userID

Comment: Please don't mix old implicit join syntax and modern explicit join syntax, too confusing for most people!

Comment: @KarthikeyanS - `tblApplications` is needed to answer the `Status - If he has visited the applicationID 3 or not.`

Comment: @jarlh - you are right, I could use `CROSS JOIN` to get Cartesian product between `tblUsers` and `tblApplications`, but why not use it since it's not deprecated ?

Comment: tblLogs is the transaction table which contains userID and application ID that he has accessed

Comment: it depends on how the information is used. one way is to query data, and if there is a result then `these are the students who accessed a particular application`, another way is to show the questioned application id, and within the result have the `status` ( did they access or not the particular application ), and since you want to have a `status`, then Cartesian product is the way to go !

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check the status.

**Query**

```
select t1.UserId, t1.UserName,
max(case when t1.UserId in 
    (select UserId from tblLogs where ApplicationID = 3) then 'Visited'
else 'Not Visited' end) as `status`
from tblUsers t1
left join tblLogs t2
on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
group by t1.UserId, t1.UserName;
```

[**SQl Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc470/13)

Comment: Thanks, this might work but can it be done without relying on max key word